# problem running eclipse on ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, java

I downloaded eclipse on ubuntu. But when I run it it show following error.

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/home/awan/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

Can someone help me to solve this. I don't have experience about this on ubuntu.

thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to install either the `openjdk-7-jre` or `oracle-java7-jre` package.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Note that `openjdk-7-jre` is easier to install, because it's available via the standard Ubuntu repository, whereas you have to build `oracle-java7-jre` yourself using `java-package`.

Comment: It should be like this: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre`

Comment: @RAJ Once upon a time, in a previous release of Debian (and probably Ubuntu), `aptitude` was vastly more capable than, and preferred over, `apt-get`. Times have changed, though, and `apt-get` is indeed more favoured these days, which is why I approve of the edit on my post.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young thumbs up.. :)

Comment: Not sure it is a very good idea if you are having multiple jres.

Comment: For installing the latest version of openjdk, you can search the latest openjdk version by `sudo apt-cache search openjdk` and install the latest version of openjdk-xx-jre (should be shown towards the end)

Answer (score 28):

If you allready installed java** you need to add the Java-Path to your [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

in my case it's located at:

```
/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

there you need to add direct under the "openFile" statement, where you replace the path with your java path:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin/java    //!replace with your path to java!
```

** check wether java is installed by typing the commands

```
java -version
```

or

```
javac -version
```

If you are sure that java is installed, but it's not found you may have multiple versions installed, check that by:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select installation first

Comment: same scenario with Oracle JDK "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
"

Comment: This is also needed if you installed eclipse with one java version and than changed java version.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior Yes, when Linux updates java, eclipse crashes because it has an older version location in `eclipse.ini`

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by created a symbolic link `java` in `/usr/bin` that points to the VM.

**Steps :**

1. Downloaded the appropriate version of Oracle's JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp
2. extract it to any folder. For example :

   tar zxvf ~/Downloads/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz ~/DEV
3. create symbolic link with name `java` :

   `cd /usr/bin`

   `ln -s ~/DEV/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java java`

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the JDK to your PATH.

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/44275/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path-in-ubuntu) link should help you get started.

Comment: I added the JDK to the path, but it did not resolve the issue. I had to create a symbolic link `java` in `usr/bin` to point to the vm. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24710592/2105986

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the JDK or OpenJDK (Eclipse only officially supports the former, but the latter mostly works).

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error message by adding jre path in to **eclipse.ini**.To solve the error like this,your machine should have java installed.
In my setup **eclipse.ini** is in 
`eclipse-jee-mars-linux-gtk-x86_64-5.0.0/eclipse` folder.

Add,

```
-vm /home/user/Documents/Softwares/jdk-8u202-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_202/jre/bin
```

at the top of the file.

In here `/home/user/Documents/Softwares/jdk-8u202-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_202` is my `JAVA_HOME`

For me, directing **JDK path** to `-vm` didn't work.I had to put the **jre/bin** path which is inside jdk folder.

Comment: I tried adding `.../jre` and `.../jre/bin/java` to `$PATH` (b/c error message stated "java in your current PATH"), and was going to try `.../jre/bin` but moved on to other attempts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a Java environment that can execute the Java instructions in Eclipse for it to run.

Install a suitable Java package in the package manager, and try again.   Note that Eclipse does not require a JDK, a JRE is enough.

Comment: Sometimes, knowing the right package name makes all the difference, especially for a new user. "A suitable Java package" may be above the OP's knowledge level.

Comment: ørn: Yeah, totally agree. :-( Normally, in later versions of Ubuntu, you use the "Software Centre", but I've never used it (because I'm a command-line geek) and therefore can't give detailed directions for it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried editing .profile, .bashrc, to no avail.  (I'm trying to use eclipse by clicking an icon, NOT by executing it from a bash shell).

SOLUTION:  I copied my /home/denise/jdk1.7.0_25/jre  to 
/home/denise/dev//jre

which is a stupid solution because it defeats the purpose of having a .profile or .bashrc.

and no, there was no .pam_environment file

peace!

Comment: Is this an answer? Think before you answer this way

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. It solved after, I have download JRE from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

and put it in the path of eclipse as shown below -

abc@ubuntu:~/Downloads/eclipse$ ls

about_files
configuration
eclipse.ini
icon.xpm
p2
about.html
dropins
epl-v10.html
**jre**
plugins
artifacts.xml
eclipse
features
notice.html
readme

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set your JAVA path in .bashrc file.
goto `cd ~`
open .bashrc,`vi .bashrc`
add a line at the end `export path="path/to dir:$path"`
do `source .bashrc` for changes to take effect.

Then open your eclipse.ini file(if you want to locate eclipse.ini do `whereis eclipse`).
open eclipse.ini,then add a line

```
-vm
"path/to/bin/of/open-jdk"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy jre and paste in eclipse folder that's it. After this just click on eclipse icon to launch eclipse. Thanks.

artifacts.xml
configuration
dropins
eclipse
eclipse.ini
features
icon.xpm
**jre**
p2
plugins
readme

Comment: I made it in Bold.