# HOW to run or install eclipse kepler and jdk in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:

```
 /home/raghib/Desktop/eclipse/jre/bin/java
```

java in your current PATH

and i have jdk tar file but how to install them... or could anyone tell how to chnege the location path

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem running eclipse on ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771227/problem-running-eclipse-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Is that you are getting errors in already installed java? Or do you want to install java fresh?

Answer (score 0):

With ubuntu u have to write some coding for installation of anything or u can just use ubuntu's eclipse which is present in it's applications. Following link may help you http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-eclipse-java-ide/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Its better if you can tell the steps instead. This link get be someday when people will need it.

Comment: It' not recommended to use any Eclipse that is provided by a linux package tool; best to get it directly from the source at www.eclipse.org