# A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse Installer

Tags: java, eclipse

I am facing an error when I install eclipse oxygen in Ubuntu 18.04

I have already installed JRE and JDK, still getting this error.

When I run this command `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` in terminal

and then this command `~/Downloads/eclipse-inst-linux64/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst` but still giving the same error.

How should I fix this error?

**A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse Installer. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: /absolute/path/to/jre6/bin**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem running eclipse on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771227/problem-running-eclipse-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I run this line `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` but still showing the error

Comment: I think you should check the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320939/9218757), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771248/9218757) as well. Install jdk only seem not enough?

Comment: @DangNguyen.. thank you for providing a links

Comment: Java 8 or higher is required to run the Eclipse Installer or a (directly downloaded) IDE package.